# SQL Server error creating stored procedure

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

I'm trying to create a simple stored procedure but getting a strange error. I'm sysadmin on the server.

When I run the following code, I get this error

> Msg 15151, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
>   Cannot find the object 'Paul', because it does not exist or you do not
>   have permission. The statement has been terminated.

I can create the procedure in the dbo schema and then transfer it into the schema. I have tried this on a few different installations of 2008 (R1 & R2) and it sometimes works and mostly doesn't.

Does anyone have any suggestions? Thanks Paul.

```
if not exists (Select * from sys.schemas Where name = 'Test')
    Exec ('Create Schema Test Authorization dbo')

IF  EXISTS (SELECT * FROM sys.objects WHERE object_id = OBJECT_ID(N'[Test].[Paul]') AND type in (N'P', N'PC'))
    DROP PROCEDURE [Test].[Paul]
GO

Create Procedure Test.Paul
As
    Select @@ServerName
GO

Create Procedure dbo.[Paul]
As
    Select @@ServerName
GO

Alter Schema Test Transfer dbo.Paul

exec Test.Paul1

IF  EXISTS (SELECT * FROM sys.schemas WHERE name = N'Test')
    DROP SCHEMA [Test]
GO
```

Comment: which line is the error? as I see Alter Schema Test Transfer dbo.Paul should fail because Procedure Test.Paul was already created

Comment: Sorry I was trying to prove that the first Create Statement failed, but I was then able to execute the second one in the dbo schema and then transfer it to the correct schema(test). So run each piece of code and check the error.

Comment: I'm getting : `Msg 15530, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
The object with name "Paul" already exists.` on the line `Alter Schema Test Transfer dbo.Paul` since the `Test.Paul` stored proc already exists...

Comment: The code sounds like it works on the instance you have tested on. Can you tell me what version of SQL you have used. I have the failure on 2008 R1

Comment: The problem seems to be confined to the database I am using. I am able to run the code fine in the master database. I will investigate the configuration of the database more.

Comment: I tested your code on SQL Server 2008 R2 (SP1)

Answer (score 0):

SPE109, check whether you can alter the existing Test.Paul sp. Please verify the Alter/Dropping permission for login user.

Use following statements to grant permission

```
GRANT EXEC ON some_sp TO uname-- Grant permission on a single procedure.
GRANT EXEC ON SCHEMA::dbo TO uname -- Grant perpmission on all procedures in
                                      the dbo schema

GRANT CREATE TABLE TO uname

GRANT ALTER ON SCHEMA::dbo TO uname
```

Now try to drop the SP

Comment: [Test] is the schema name not the database name. So your code would try and create the procedure in a database called test, but put the procedure in the dbo schema.

Comment: Once I have transferred the procedure to the test schema, I have generated the drop and create script, this fails. I have altered the procedure by adding a new column. I have full sysadmin rights on the SQL instance so have permission to do everything I need to.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry to waste your time guys, it seems that someone has put on a database level trigger which doesn't deal with Schema's properly. So it is the trigger that is erroring and not the create procedure.

Thanks for you help and suggestions.
Paul.